# implicit declaration of function ‘rand_r’

Tags: c, makefile

I know there are a lot of questions with a similar title, but so far I have not found one that could solve my situation.

When making the file, I got prompted with

```
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘rand_r’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

But I have already included `stdlib.h` and `unistd.h`, why is it still happening? Is it because of the makefile?

I am running this on Linux and my makefile is roughly as follows:

```
prog: prog.o
    gcc -g -o $@ $^ -lpthread

%.o:%.c *.h
    gcc -ansi -pedantic -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wreturn-type -g -c $< -o $@
```

Thank you

Comment: Whereas I agree that `-ansi` is a likely reason for this issue, I find that it does not cause such a problem with the relatively old version of GCC that I presently have at hand.  A [mre] would help, as another possibility would be explicit (un)definition of feature test macros in the program source.

Comment: @JohnBollinger sounds like your version is non-conforming

Comment: I wouldn't say that, @M.M. Certainly it does not for that reason fail to conform to C90 / ANSI C.  Nor does it appear to fail to conform to the GCC manual (any version), wherein I find nothing to indicate that I would be justified in *expecting* it to warn, though I do find provisions that indicate that I shouldn't be surprised if it does warn.  Note also that in C90, the compiler is required to accept calls to undeclared functions -- this is not an extension in that case.

Comment: @JohnBollinger what happens if your prorgram contains `float rand_r(float f);` (and `#include <stdlib.h>`) ?

Comment: Good experiment, @M.M.  With `-ansi`, such a program is accepted.  Without, it is rejected with a conflicting types error.  But I have tracked down the issue: I had dropped the `-Wimplicit-function-declaration` because the version of GCC I am testing on is old enough not to recognize it, and somehow expected it to be on by default. When I added `-Wimplicit`, I got the diagnostic.

Comment: the prototype for `rand_r()` is in the header file: `stdlib.h` not `stdio.h` nor `unistd.h`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rand_r()` [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/3/rand_r) reads:

> The functions rand() and srand() conform to SVr4, 4.3BSD, C89, C99, POSIX.1-2001. The function rand_r() is from POSIX.1-2001. POSIX.1-2008 marks rand_r() as obsolete.

Your compilation options specify `-ansi` (C89/C90) thus limiting you to `rand()` and `srand()`.

Comment: I see. After removing the `-ansi` the warning did disappeared, I think it's working. Thank you!

Comment: @John Now fixed. The problem I guess is that only `stdlib.h` is included. Nothing prevents `rand_r()` to be defined elsewhere, but a conforming `stdlib.h` should not include it.